# Stick two gray images back to back in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have two gray images and I want to stick these two images back-to-back along the third dimension and form a **WxHx2** images. The generated image is then labeled and feed to the Tensorflow framework for training. How I can do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape image1 and image2 to be of shape (H, W, 1) and do

`x = numpy.dstack((image1, image2))`

to make x to have shape (H, W, 2) which you can feed into any tensorflow as input.